Enabling GKE API on Shared VPC Host project
Today I faced an error while setting up a GKE cluster in a Shared VPC network.
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: Failed precondition when calling the ServiceConsumerManager:
tenantmanager::XXXXXX: com.google.api.tenant.error.TenantManagerException: 
Consumer <Shared VPC Project ID> should enable service:container.googleapis.com before generating a service account.


While it is easy to fix, I am wondering, what is the reason behind the requirement to enable container.googleapis.com on both Host and Service projects?
It is obvious that you have to enable it on the Service project and grant permissions while the purpose of enabling it on the Host project seems redundant.
See GKE setup with Sharev VPC

I suspect (because it's not very clear in the docs) that it's because of the control plane. Since that element is Google Managed it could be asociated in the host project and for that it requires the api to be enabled also there

The Host Project manages the Shared VPC, enabling the GKE API that allows the project to handle networking resources (ex. Firewall, subnets) while the Service Project uses the Shared network resources for deploying workloads, like your GKE clusters.
See this Shared VPC scenario for additional information.

